# How to convert int to hex in python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, arc4random

I try to run spritz encryption code in python . which it have to convert in to hex. The same code is

```
   result = self.s.int_to_hex(self.s.hash(256, self.s.int_string("ABC"), 32))
   print(result)
```

It have no error but I want to reduce permutation array from 256 to 16. So I change the code like this.

```
       result = self.s.int_to_hex(self.s.hash(16, self.s.int_string("ABC"), 32))
       print(result)
```

Then it show error like this.

```
.E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_hash (__main__.TestSpritz)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 9, in test_hash
    result = self.s.int_to_hex(self.s.hash(16, self.s.int_string("ABC"), 32))
  File "C:/Python34\spritz.py", line 130, in hash
    self.absorb(M)
  File "C:/Python34\spritz.py", line 73, in absorb
    self.absorb_byte(byte)
  File "C:/Python34\spritz.py", line 68, in absorb_byte
    self.absorb_nibble(self.high(b))
  File "C:/Python34\spritz.py", line 63, in absorb_nibble
    self.S[self.a], self.S[int(math.floor(self.N/2)+x)] = self.S[int(math.floor(self.N/2)+x)], self.S[self.a]
IndexError: list index out of range

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.031s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I don't know how to use function int_to_hex please help me.

This is my code.

**test.py**

```
import unittest
from spritz import Spritz

class TestSpritz(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.s = Spritz()

    def test_hash(self):
        result = self.s.int_to_hex(self.s.hash(16, self.s.int_string("ABC"), 32))
        print(result)
        self.assertEqual(result[0:16], '028FA2B48B934A18')
        result = self.s.int_to_hex(self.s.hash(256, self.s.int_string("spam"), 32))
        self.assertEqual(result[0:16], 'ACBBA0813F300D3A')
        result = self.s.int_to_hex(self.s.hash(256, self.s.int_string("arcfour"), 32))
        self.assertEqual(result[0:16], 'FF8CF268094C87B9')

    def test_encryption(self):
        result = self.s.array_to_string(self.s.encrypt(self.s.int_string("ABC"), [0]*8))
        self.assertEqual(result, '779A8E01F9E9CBC0')
        result = self.s.array_to_string(self.s.encrypt(self.s.int_string("spam"), [0]*8))
        self.assertEqual(result, 'F0609A1DF143CEBF')
        result = self.s.array_to_string(self.s.encrypt(self.s.int_string("arcfour"), [0]*8))
        self.assertEqual(result, '1AFA8B5EE337DBC7')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**spritz.py**

```
import math
from fractions import gcd

class Spritz():
    alt = False
    def initialize_state(self, N_input):
        self.i = 0
        self.j = 0
        self.k = 0
        self.z = 0
        self.a = 0
        self.w = 1
        self.N = N_input
        self.D = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(self.N)))
        self.S = list(range(self.N))

    def low(self, b):
        return b % self.D

    def high(self, b):
        return int(math.floor(b/self.D))

    def update(self):
        self.i = (self.i + self.w) % self.N
        self.j = (self.k + self.S[(self.j + self.S[self.i]) % self.N]) % self.N
        self.k = (self.i + self.k + self.S[self.j]) % self.N
        self.S[self.i], self.S[self.j] = self.S[self.j], self.S[self.i]

    def whip(self, r):
        for v in list(range(r)):
            self.update()
        self.w = (self.w + 1) % self.N
        while gcd(self.w, self.N) != 1:
            self.w = (self.w + 1) % self.N

    def crush(self):
        for v in list(range(int(math.floor(self.N/2)))):
            if self.S[v] > self.S[self.N-1-v]:
                self.S[v], self.S[self.N-1-v] = self.S[self.N-1-v], self.S[v]

    def alt_crush(self):
        for v in list(range(int(math.floor(self.N/2)))):
            x = self.S[v]
            y = self.S[N-1-v]
            if x > y:
                self.S[v] = y
                self.S[N-1-v] = x
            else:
                self.S[v] = x
                self.S[N-1-v] = y

    def shuffle(self):
        self.whip(2*self.N)
        self.alt_crush() if self.alt else self.crush()
        self.whip(2*self.N)
        self.alt_crush() if self.alt else self.crush()
        self.whip(2*self.N)
        self.a = 0

    def absorb_nibble(self, x):
        if self.a == int(math.floor(self.N/2)):
            self.shuffle()
        self.S[self.a], self.S[int(math.floor(self.N/2)+x)] = self.S[int(math.floor(self.N/2)+x)], self.S[self.a]
        self.a = (self.a + 1) % self.N

    def absorb_byte(self, b):
        self.absorb_nibble(self.low(b))
        self.absorb_nibble(self.high(b))

    def absorb(self, I):
        for v in list(range(0, len(I), 3)):
            byte = int(I[v:v+3])
            self.absorb_byte(byte)

    def absorb_stop(self):
        if self.a == int(math.floor(self.N/2)):
            self.shuffle()
        self.a = (self.a + 1) % self.N

    def output(self):
        self.z = self.S[(self.j + self.S[(self.i + self.S[(self.z + self.k) % self.N]) % self.N]) % self.N]
        return self.z

    def drip(self):
        if self.a > 0:
            self.shuffle()
        self.update()
        return self.output()

    def squeeze(self, r):
        if self.a > 0:
            self.shuffle()
        P = ""
        for v in list(range(r)):
            #P.append("%0.2X" % self.drip())
            P += "%03d" % self.drip()
        return P

    def print_variables(self):
        print ("i: " + hex(self.i))
        print ("j: " + hex(self.j))
        print ("k: " + hex(self.k))
        print ("z: " + hex(self.z))
        print ("a: " + hex(self.a))
        print ("w: " + hex(self.w))
        print ("D: " + hex(self.D))
        print ("S: " + self.array_to_string(self.S))
        #print "S: " + str(self.S)

    def int_string(self, string):
        key = ""
        for char in string:
            key += "%03d" % ord(char)
        return key

    def int_to_hex(self, int_string):
        result = ""
        for i in list(range(0, len(int_string), 3)):
            result += "%0.2X" % int(int_string[i:i+3])
        return result

    def array_to_string(self, array):
        result = ""
        for i in array:
            result += "%0.2X" % i
        return result

    def hash(self, N, M, r):
        self.initialize_state(N)
        self.absorb(M)
        self.absorb_stop()
        self.absorb_byte(r)
        return self.squeeze(r)

    def key_setup(self, K):
        self.initialize_state(256)
        self.absorb(K)

    def encrypt(self, K, M):
        self.key_setup(K)
        Z_string = self.squeeze(len(M))
        Z = [int(Z_string[i:i+3]) for i in list(range(0, len(Z_string), 3))]
        C = [i + j for i, j in zip(M, Z)]
        return C
```